# How to get the raw JSON response of a HTTP request from `driver.page_source` in Selenium webdriver Firefox

Tags: python, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver, httpresponse

If I browse to [`https://httpbin.org/headers`](https://httpbin.org/headers) I expect to get the following JSON response:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0"
  }
}
```

However, if I use Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

url = 'https://httpbin.org/headers'
driver.get(url)
print(driver.page_source)
driver.close()
```

I get

```
<html platform="linux" class="theme-light" dir="ltr"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none' ; script-src resource:; "><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource://devtools-client-jsonview/css/main.css"><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="viewer-config" src="resource://devtools-client-jsonview/viewer-config.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="json-viewer" src="resource://devtools-client-jsonview/json-viewer.js"></script></head><body><div id="content"><div id="json">{
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0"
  }
}
</div></div><script src="resource://devtools-client-jsonview/lib/require.js" data-main="resource://devtools-client-jsonview/viewer-config.js"></script></body></html>
```

Where do the HTML tags come from? How do I get the raw JSON response of a HTTP request from `driver.page_source`?

Comment: If you'd do F12 and switch to Inspector tab you will see HTML also, not JSON. It has nothing to do with Selenium

Comment: You can use tool like [`python-requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and get raw source like `requests.get('https://httpbin.org/headers').json()` without handling DOM

Comment: @Andersson thinking of it, I'm quite positive httpbin.org should be serving different content based on the `Accept` header in the request. The default value for python's `requests` is "*/*", so the server falls back to application-json - thus the outcome of your test is not an exception (the `.json()` would've raised one, if the response was an html string).

Comment: @TodorMinakov , depends on type of response one might use `.text` or `.content`, but since question was *"How to get the raw JSON response..."* I've used `.json()`

Comment: I meant something different (not "which property of the response object should be used"), probably didn't explain myself clearly - httpbin.org is returning different data for different clients; that's based on the "Accept" header. For browser clients it is returning html, with a node having the "json" as a value; for clients that can accept it - like the `requests` lib - it is returning directly the json response. Thus the code in your comment worked out of the box - the server did not return the "shielding html", the payload in the response was a proper json.

Comment: I did try it (now, that I'm in front of a computer), and realized I have written as an answer totally incorrect information - it's now deleted. The server does respond with a normal json - regardless of the "Accept" header in the request, and that response has `Content-Type: application/json`. So all the html that is around it is injected by the browser (Firefox), to present a pretty-print of the json response. I stand corrected.

Comment: @Andersson "If you'd do F12 and switch to Inspector tab you will see HTML also, not JSON. "
The HTML you see there comes from your browser. Obviously, your browser wraps your JSON data into HTML, so that it can display something nice, not just a text string, like with plain text files. The server in OP's question does indeed only send json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the raw JSON response, `driver.page_source` also contains the HTML to "pretty print" the response in the browser. You'll get the same result, if you use the Firefox DOM and Style Inspector to view the source of the JSON response in the browser.

To get the raw JSON response you can navigate the HTML elements as usual:

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='json']").text)
```

Answer (score 18):

use the "view-source:" parameter in your url

**Simple Mode:**

example:

```
url = 'view-source:https://httpbin.org/headers'
driver.get(url)
content = driver.page_source
print(content)
```

output:

```
'<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"><title>https://httpbin.org/headers</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource://content-accessible/viewsource.css"></head><body id="viewsource" class="highlight" style="-moz-tab-size: 4"><pre>{\n  "headers": {\n    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", \n    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", \n    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", \n    "Host": "httpbin.org", \n    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", \n    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"\n  }\n}\n</pre></body></html>'
```

**Best Mode: (for JSON)**

example:

```
url = 'view-source:https://httpbin.org/headers'
driver.get(url)
content = driver.page_source
content = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('pre').text
parsed_json = json.loads(content)
print(parsed_json)
```

output:

```
{'headers': {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'Host': 'httpbin.org',
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0'}}
```

Answer (score 7):

This article helped me to solve the issue with firefox: https://blog.francium.tech/firefox-selenium-disable-json-formatting-cfaf466fd20f

I've added this preference to my driver factory:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions

    @staticmethod
    def get_firefox_options(headless):
        options = FirefoxOptions()
        options.set_preference('devtools.jsonview.enabled', False)

        if headless:
            options.headless = True

        return options
```

Comment: I consider this answer to be more professional than fiddling with urls or fetching json from a ton of data as suggested in other answers.

Comment: Life saver, thank you.  Cannot stand when "upgrades" break things.