# Adding a row to a sheet using Sheety and Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, python-requests

I’ve been trying to practice adding a row to a spreadsheet using Sheety, and I cannot get it to work. I keep getting this error:

requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.sheety.co/34f63563bea12bad1332ca8a5bb3cae6/workoutTrackerSheet/workouts

My code is as follows:

```
    import requests
    from datetime import datetime
    
    SHEET_ENDPOINT = "https://api.sheety.co/34f63563bea12bad1332ca8a5bb3cae6/workoutTrackerSheet/workouts"
    
    today = datetime.now()
    date_string = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    time_string = today.strftime("%X")
    
    data_for_sheet = {
        "workouts": {
            "date": date_string,
            "time": time_string,
            "exercise": "exercise",
            "duration": "duration",
            "calories": "calories"
        }
    }
    
    response = requests.post(url=SHEET_ENDPOINT, json=data_for_sheet)
    response.raise_for_status()
```

I have been careful to nest my JSON object in a root property named after my sheet, “workouts”. am using the same gmail account for both Sheety and my Google account. I have made sure that Sheety has permission to access my Google sheets.

---

UPDATE:
My mistake was the the root property of the json passed to requests.post() ought to have been "workout", not "workouts", as in the Sheety documentation: [1].

I don't really understand *why* this is the case, however - since the API endpoint ends in "workouts" and this is also the name of the sheet. If anyone can explain why the "s" must be dropped, I would appreciate it.
[1]: https://sheety.co/docs/requests.html

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Your worksheet is called "workouts" but it's going to be "workout" when calling a post request, that's because:

"Sheety expects your record to be nested in a singular root property named after your sheet. For example if your endpoint is named emails, nest your record in a property called email"

[here](https://sheety.co/docs/requests.html#:%7E:text=Sheety%20expects%20your%20record%20to%20be%20nested%20in%20a%20singular%20root%20property%20named%20after%20your%20sheet.%20For%20example%20if%20your%20endpoint%20is%20named%20emails%2C%20nest%20your%20record%20in%20a%20property%20called%20email) is the link where sheety api talked about it.
That's it, please also note that sheety api camelCases all the json keys too, so "First Name" will become "firstName". What is camelCase? [here](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/CamelCase).

Answer (score 0):

You can get this json using Selenium.

[how-to-get-the-raw-json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54024428/how-to-get-the-raw-json-response-of-a-http-request-from-driver-page-source-in)

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


url = 'view-source:https://api.sheety.co/34f63563bea12bad1332ca8a5bb3cae6/workoutTrackerSheet/workouts'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(url)
content = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.line-content')

# We collect all the found page elements into a string and convert it to json.

elem = ""
for el in content:
    elem += el.text

parsed_json = json.loads(elem)
print(parsed_json)

driver.quit()

----------------------------------

{'workouts': [{'date': '21/07/2020', 'time': '15:00:00', 'exercise': 'Running', 'duration': 22, 'calories': 130, 'id': 2}]}
```