# How can I save the website response in JSON format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Could you tell me please, is it possible to somehow save the information in a `JSON` file with the response information from the site using the `selenium library`?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the raw JSON response of a HTTP request from \`driver.page\_source\` in Selenium webdriver Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54024428/how-to-get-the-raw-json-response-of-a-http-request-from-driver-page-source-in)

Comment: you can use the python-requests module to use this api endpoint and capture the response. you don't need selenium for that. If url is public please share the url?

Comment: @mkrieger1, You are right, the answer partially satisfies me, but when I do this, a problem arises: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)`.

my code:        ` content = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'fdata').text
        parsed_json = json.loads(content)
        print(parsed_json)` the content variable contains exactly the data that I need, but alas, they are not written in `JSON`

Comment: Then don't try to parse it as JSON.